# meaning of parameters of function such as “/” res,req,next

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, ionic-framework, routes

I try to understand the code of a friend and I connect to js and nodejs for the first time,I want to know the meaning of "/" , req res next.
here is the code

in routes/task.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Task = require('../models/task');
router.post("/", function(req, res, next){
    var task = req.body;
    Task.create(task, function(err, task){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send("err in post /task");
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json(task);
        }
    });
});
router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    Task.find({}, function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send("err in get /task");
        }else{
            console.log(tasks);
            return res.status(200).json(tasks);
        }
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

Task is a data module exports in models/task.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  create_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", TaskSchema);
```

Comment: read the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is to attach HTTP method request handlers using Express's [router](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router) object for the webapp.